# Simple socket communication program is not working at all

Tags: java, sockets, ipc

Server accepts multiple connections using threads.

Server:

```
@Override
public void run () {
    try {
        System.out.println(client);
        System.out.println("Client Connected");
        //So far, so good. Client is connected

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(this.client.getInputStream()));
        System.out.println(in.readLine());
        // Nothing happens
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Client:

```
try {
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(Client.socket.getOutputStream());
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader (
                new InputStreamReader(Client.socket.getInputStream()));

        out.write("Information sent from client");
        // Does not work
        in.read();
        // Before this .read it would give a "Connection reset" probably
        // Because the client closed before the server could even read
    }
```

No error, but it just hangs, nothing is being sent. Firewall is down so it can't be that. Also it used to work yesterday. I have no idea what I could have messed up.

Comment: Did you try using net cat to replace the client and server separately to see which works?

Comment: `readline()` relies on a newline, as per the docs. You aren't sending one so it will block and never return.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`write`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#write%28java.lang.String%29) writes the content only to the `InputStream`. Use [`println`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#println%28java.lang.String%29) to send an additional newline character to correspond to the `readLine` statement on the server.

```
out.println("Information sent from client");
```

Comment: Oh, so no newline character means the server just waits until one comes (which would be never) ? Thank you. Works.